# How to open non-launcher activity on notification group click

Tags: android

Currently I have this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, DigestPager.class);
```

and this is opening `DigestPager` activity (which is not launcher activity) when clicking on a single notification.

But when there are multiple notifications and they are grouped into one and collapsed, clicking on it is opening launcher activity.

Is there some simple way to open a different activity?

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, DigestPager.class);
resultIntent.putExtra("digestId", digest.getDigestId());

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, digest.getDigestId(), resultIntent,
           PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotifyMgr.notify(digest.getDigestId(), mBuilder.build());
```

Comment: you can open using PendaingIntents.Try it

Comment: That's what I'm currently using. For single notification click.

Comment: did you find a solution to this ? If yes, pls post it. I am in search of same

Comment: have you solved your issue? I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler activity that opens everytime you click on a notification and based on the flags set to the notification, you can navigate to the required activity/fragment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thing is that I can't handle the intent when clicking on notification group. It's opening launcher activity and not passing any extras.